# How to turn off folders transliteration in Nuxt Content?

Tags: nuxt.js

I use Nuxt 3 and its Content module.

When I fetch my `/content/` folder structure the .md files are returned as-is, while folders are transliterated into latin.

Nothing special to provide regarding code, but just in case, here is how I fetch it:

```
const { data: navigation } = await useAsyncData('home', async () => {
  const query = queryContent({
    where: {
      _path: { $contains: '/lessons/' }
    }
  })

  return fetchContentNavigation(query)
})
```

And, for example, one of the folders is called "Базовая грамматика". When I output the `navigation` via console.log, I can see that title is "Bazovaya Grammatika".

I tried googling and even asked ChatGPT, who suggested using `transpile: false` in nuxt config.

But it didn't help.

Comment: It's not a `transpile` issue here for sure. How do you wish to have your URLs? In Russian rather than English? Then, you probably need to look for i18n to either superset Nuxt context or extend Nuxt content with some different i18n configuration.

Comment: I got it, I explained things wrongly. I was talking about displaying links in navigation, and for each .md file that I created I added frontmatter attribute "title". But I didn't know how to do that for folders. So when I looped through folders, the folder title was in Latin. But there is _dir.yml config that can be used for each folder, just found it in docs